# Data driven tests in Silk4Net

Tags: data-driven-tests, silktest

Is there any support in Silk4Net for data-driven tests? Should we code it from scratch or is there any support like Parameterized tests in JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silk forum shows that [Silk4Net is MSTest based](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/f/29/p/12094/20657.aspx#20657), and [MSTest supports Datasource attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx) for data driven tests.